# How to abandon (switch from) a branch that requires merging?

Tags: git, git-merge

After a `git pull`, my branch requires merging but the merge seems so tedious that I simply just want to abandon my branch and start applying my changes from scratch.  I tried to `git stash` but it wouldn't let me because of the required merges.  Is there any way for me to force stash or abandon the branch and switch to another, clean one?  I can't `checkout` another branch either so it seems like I am stuck having to merge the branch, which I don't want to do.

Comment: will that undo my local changes that need to be merged in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git pull` does a `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. You are now stuck with merge conflicts, and want to abort the merge.

You can use `git merge --abort` to stop merging. After that, you can continue with for example `git checkout` or whatever it is that you want to do. Your branch stays as it was, only the merge is aborted.